# Gmail NodeMailer Invalid Status Code 401

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer with gmail. It was working fine, but now I am suddenly receiving the error:

> Invalid Status Code 401

There aren't any further details on the error. I have already refreshed the token by following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), however I am still not able to solve this. Here is my nodemailer code:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  port: 25,
  service: 'gmail',
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'first.last@example.com',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    refreshToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); <-- BOOM Fails here now
    return;
  }
});
```

Any suggestions on how to solve or debug this would be very appreciated.